# Installation Ubuntu server on top of an existing one

Tags: server, php, nodejs, lan, realtime

Actually I'm developing a web application using PHP and realtime Chat application and notications using NodeJs.

In a Local network There is an ubuntu server to connect some windows machines to make a Local network and a sharing some files.

There is any possibility to install another server on top of this server and allow connections ONLY and STRCLTY ONLY from the local machines?
Those machines change there IP automatically "normal"  because they are connected to the www.

Can I do something like this ?
The reason basically to protect my application from cloning and the second reason to do not interfere with the existing solution because if the server down all the business down with it.

I'm not good in this field  but I'm trying to it with a safer manipulation for all people.
This is an opportunity for me to get in this field :)
Thank you

Comment: Possible? Sure. However, your statement that your server is business-critical suggests that you're in a high-risk situation. Were this one of my systems, all would be arranged with proper containers and backups to easily create a safe testing sandbox for you to develop within without threat to your business-critical services. However, it's not one of my systems, and you have not told us how the admin has that server set up. We have insufficient information to advise you safely.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, then the simplest solution would be to set up a Docker container for your application and use firewall rules to drop all traffic that is not from the local network. Alternatively, you could set up a VM on any machine on the network and do the same thing. This would offer a more traditional form of server management.

Comment: **Warning** Stories that begin with "I'm a beginner ... business critical system" NEVER end well.

Comment: @user535733 : critical yes because they are connected to an external CRM, Cloud, internet and some private B2B Services and the work is synchronized in some how with a business clients. I'm really don't know how to say it but the IT guy is freelancer and not available all the time. I will try to reach him tomorrow if possible how. What information you think valuable to ask and make a better vision? For now what I know is an ubuntu serv with disk 2Tb and they use a small space for sharing some files and all outgoing requests go throw it to the router then to internet that's all what I knw.

Comment: @matigo: thanks I will try this on my laptop using Virtual box and Ubuntu server iso

Comment: @Warning: almost yes. But I'm not pressed for now because the software in development phase and it takes time. So I'm anticipating.

Comment: You are right to use a VM. When your tool ready for prime-time, then it's that freelancer's job to safely integrate it into your network. So keep notes on how you built it -- you might need to rebuild it right in front of that freelancer in order to show them the resources it needs.